# Jmeter- statistics from all Listeners

Tags: java, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

In jmeter I run my test from console and save results to jtl file:

```
jmeter -n -t file.jmx -l stat.jtl
```

But I want to see also data for other Listeners: for example - Summary Report etc.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can reload the stat.jtl file at end of load test in all the Listeners by entering the file name in the "Filename" field.

You may also be interested in:

- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/automatically-generating-nice-graphs-at-end-of-your-load-test-with-apache-jmeter-and-jmeter-plugins/